# OSMBonusPack route steps in german?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

i build a route with OSMBonusPach and Graphhopper.

Is it possible to show "route steps" in german language

I using:
- Android
- OSMdroid
- OSMBonusPack
- Graphhopper

Comment: In GraphHopper you can do this via the parameter locale=de. So you need to pass this to osmbonuspack somehow :)

Comment: Thank you :) do you have a example or the android command for me? :)

Comment: It should be `roadManager.addRequestOption("locale=de");` https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1

Comment: @J.Doe If the answer helped you please mark it with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1), this should make it

```
roadManager.addRequestOption("locale=de");
```